# Python/arcpy 32 bit and 64 bit problems

Tags: arcpy, python

I have a 32 bit and 64 bit python installs, both 2.7 with arcpy

Paths to python.exe

```
32 bit path = C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4
64 bit path = C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.4
```

now in my environmental variables:

for my "user variable for user" top tab

variable name = PYTHONPATH
variable value = C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.4;C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4

and in the system variables I have added the exact same variable name and variable values

**PROBLEM**

The very import package arcpy only successfully imports and works in the 64 bit version but does not work when I try and import arcpy with the 32 bit version. it gives me this error with the 32 bit

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\ArcPy\arcpy\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from . import function_base
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\function_base.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .numeric import (result_type, NaN, shares_memory, MAY_SHARE_BOUNDS,
ImportError: cannot import name shares_memory
```

BUT here is what is even stranger. when i cmd over to the 64 bit install of python and try and install a library with pip, it installs it in the 32 bit directory!!!

```
C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.4\Scripts>pip install pypdf2
```

this ends up in the 32 bit directory and not the 64 bit. I cannot import pypdf2 with the 64 bit.

So in essence I can use arcpy with 64 bit but no other modules, and I cannot use arcpy with the 32 bit but can use all the modules that are installed via pip.

I am not sure what to do here.I dont know how to properly set the env variables for my python path(i have tried just having the 32 bit alone and 64 bit python variable paths alone but the same problem exists).

when I run `import os; print repr(os.environ).replace(',', '\n')`

32 bit:

```
{'TMP': 'C:\\Users\\rizagha\\AppData\\Local\\Temp'
 'COMPUTERNAME': 'ARCSERVER'
 'VS140COMNTOOLS': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\Tools\\'
 'USERDOMAIN': 'HIGHLANDS'
 'PYTHON': 'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.4;'
 'PSMODULEPATH': 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\Modules\\'
 'COMMONPROGRAMFILES': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files'
 'PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER': 'Intel64 Family 6 Model 45 Stepping 7
 GenuineIntel'
 'POSTGIS_GDAL_ENABLED_DRIVERS': 'GTiff PNG JPEG GIF XYZ DTED USGSDEM AAIGrid'
 'PROGRAMFILES': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)'
 'PROCESSOR_REVISION': '2d07'
 'PATH': 'C:\\Oracle_Client;C:\\ProgramData\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\Windows Live;c:\\Program Files (x86)\\AMD APP\\bin\\x86_64;c:\\Program Files (x86)\\AMD APP\\bin\\x86;C:\\Windows\\system32;C:\\Windows;C:\\Windows\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Intel\\Services\\IPT\\;c:\\Program Files (x86)\\ATI Technologies\\ATI.ACE\\Core-Static;C:\\Program Files\\Dell\\Dell Data Protection\\Access\\Advanced\\Wave\\Gemalto\\Access Client\\v5\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Security Innovation\\SI TSS\\bin\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Live\\Shared;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Enterprise Vault\\EVClient\\;C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.4;C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.4\\Scripts;C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\;C:\\Users\\ishiland\\AppData\\Local\\GitHub\\PortableGit_c2ba306e536fdf878271f7fe636a147ff37326ad\\cmd;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd;C:\\Users\\rizagha\\.dnx\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft DNX\\Dnvm\\;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\130\\Tools\\Binn\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Brackets\\command'
 'SYSTEMROOT': 'C:\\Windows'
 'AMDAPPSDKROOT': 'c:\\Program Files (x86)\\AMD APP\\'
 'PROGRAMFILES(X86)': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)'
 'WINDOWS_TRACING_FLAGS': '3'
 'TEMP': 'C:\\Users\\rizagha\\AppData\\Local\\Temp'
 'COMMONPROGRAMFILES(X86)': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files'
 'PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE': 'x86'
 'AGSDESKTOPJAVA': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ArcGIS\\Desktop10.4\\'
 'ALLUSERSPROFILE': 'C:\\ProgramData'
 'LOCALAPPDATA': 'C:\\Users\\rizagha\\AppData\\Local'
 'HOMEPATH': '\\'
 'PROGRAMW6432': 'C:\\Program Files'
 'USERNAME': 'rizagha'
 'FP_NO_HOST_CHECK': 'NO'
 'LOGONSERVER': '\\\\HC-07'
 'SESSIONNAME': 'Console'
 'PROGRAMDATA': 'C:\\ProgramData'
 'PYTHONPATH': 'C:\\Python27\\ArcGISx6410.4;C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.4'
 'HOMESHARE': '\\\\hc-05\\home\\rzagha'
 'PATHEXT': '.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC'
 'ASL.LOG': 'Destination=file'
 'GDAL_DATA': 'C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.5\\gdal-data'
 'WINDIR': 'C:\\Windows'
 'WINDOWS_TRACING_LOGFILE': 'C:\\BVTBin\\Tests\\installpackage\\csilogfile.log'
 'HOMEDRIVE': 'U:'
 'SYSTEMDRIVE': 'C:'
 'COMSPEC': 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe'
 'NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS': '12'
 'APPDATA': 'C:\\Users\\rizagha\\AppData\\Roaming'
 'USERDNSDOMAIN': 
 'PROCESSOR_LEVEL': '6'
 'PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432': 'AMD64'
 'POSTGIS_ENABLE_OUTDB_RASTERS': '1'
 'COMMONPROGRAMW6432': 'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files'
 'OS': 'Windows_NT'
 'PUBLIC': 'C:\\Users\\Public'
 'USERPROFILE': 'C:\\Users\\rizagha'}
```

64 bit:

```
{'TMP': 'C:\\Users\\rizagha\\AppData\\Local\\Temp'
 'PYTHONIOENCODING': 'UTF-8'
 'COMPUTERNAME': 'ARCSERVER'
 'VS140COMNTOOLS': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\Tools\\'
 'USERDOMAIN': 'HIGHLANDS'
 'PYTHON': 'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.4;'
 'PSMODULEPATH': 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\Modules\\'
 'PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE': '1'
 'COMMONPROGRAMFILES': 'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files'
 'PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER': 'Intel64 Family 6 Model 45 Stepping 7
 GenuineIntel'
 'POSTGIS_GDAL_ENABLED_DRIVERS': 'GTiff PNG JPEG GIF XYZ DTED USGSDEM AAIGrid'
 'PROGRAMFILES': 'C:\\Program Files'
 'PROCESSOR_REVISION': '2d07'
 'SYSTEMROOT': 'C:\\Windows'
 'PATH': 'C:\\Oracle_Client;C:\\ProgramData\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\Windows Live;c:\\Program Files (x86)\\AMD APP\\bin\\x86_64;c:\\Program Files (x86)\\AMD APP\\bin\\x86;C:\\Windows\\system32;C:\\Windows;C:\\Windows\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Intel\\Services\\IPT\\;c:\\Program Files (x86)\\ATI Technologies\\ATI.ACE\\Core-Static;C:\\Program Files\\Dell\\Dell Data Protection\\Access\\Advanced\\Wave\\Gemalto\\Access Client\\v5\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Security Innovation\\SI TSS\\bin\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Live\\Shared;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Enterprise Vault\\EVClient\\;C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.4;C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.4\\Scripts;C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\;C:\\Users\\ishiland\\AppData\\Local\\GitHub\\PortableGit_c2ba306e536fdf878271f7fe636a147ff37326ad\\cmd;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd;C:\\Users\\rizagha\\.dnx\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft DNX\\Dnvm\\;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\130\\Tools\\Binn\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Brackets\\command;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ArcGIS\\Desktop10.4\\bin64'
 'PYTHONUNBUFFERED': '1'
 'AMDAPPSDKROOT': 'c:\\Program Files (x86)\\AMD APP\\'
 'PROGRAMFILES(X86)': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)'
 'WINDOWS_TRACING_FLAGS': '3'
 'TERM': 'emacs'
 'TEMP': 'C:\\Users\\rizagha\\AppData\\Local\\Temp'
 'COMMONPROGRAMFILES(X86)': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files'
 'PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE': 'AMD64'
 'AGSDESKTOPJAVA': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ArcGIS\\Desktop10.4\\'
 'ALLUSERSPROFILE': 'C:\\ProgramData'
 'LOCALAPPDATA': 'C:\\Users\\rizagha\\AppData\\Local'
 'HOMEPATH': '\\'
 'PROGRAMW6432': 'C:\\Program Files'
 'USERNAME': 'rizagha'
 'FP_NO_HOST_CHECK': 'NO'
 'LOGONSERVER': '\\\\HC-07'
 'COMSPEC': 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe'
 'PROGRAMDATA': 'C:\\ProgramData'
 'PYTHONPATH': 'C:\\Users\\rizagha\\PycharmProjects\\untitled;C:\\Python27\\ArcGISx6410.4;C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.4;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\JetBrains\\PyCharm 2016.1\\helpers\\pydev'
 'HOMESHARE': '\\\\hc-05\\home\\rzagha'
 'SESSIONNAME': 'Console'
 'PATHEXT': '.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC'
 'ASL.LOG': 'Destination=file'
 'GDAL_DATA': 'C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.5\\gdal-data'
 'WINDIR': 'C:\\Windows'
 'WINDOWS_TRACING_LOGFILE': 'C:\\BVTBin\\Tests\\installpackage\\csilogfile.log'
 'HOMEDRIVE': 'U:'
 'SYSTEMDRIVE': 'C:'
 'PYCHARM_HOSTED': '1'
 'NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS': '12'
 'APPDATA': 'C:\\Users\\rizagha\\AppData\\Roaming'
 'USERDNSDOMAIN': 
 'PROCESSOR_LEVEL': '6'
 'POSTGIS_ENABLE_OUTDB_RASTERS': '1'
 'COMMONPROGRAMW6432': 'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files'
 'OS': 'Windows_NT'
 'PUBLIC': 'C:\\Users\\Public'
 'USERPROFILE': 'C:\\Users\\rizagha'}
```

Comment: Try removing the `PYTHONPATH` variable from your environment settings.  This should force python to run from the current folder rather than environment overriding it.

Comment: Are you getting 64bit Python from Server or BG? Did you let Arc* install python, or have you installed Python yourself in either case? Did you install some package that had dependencies to update, like install X and it updated numpy to a newer version?

Comment: @KHibma I let arc install python, dont know the answer to the first question because somebody else installed it before I got this computer. a package like pypdf2 has no dependencies to update..but I did try and install geopandas which I assume would have had to update the pandas library dependencies..?

Comment: @Midavalo removed the PYTHONPATH and ran into the same problem

Comment: @ziggy If it were me I'd try doing a REPAIR install of ArcGIS and then the 64bit geoprocessing.  This should force ArcGIS to put python settings back where it wants them

Comment: when you mean repair install, do you mean uninstall and then reinstall?

Comment: @ziggy No.  Run the ArcGIS setup and you should be presented with three options: Modify, Repair, and Uninstall.  Choose repair.  Then do the same with the 64bit background geoprocessing setup.

Comment: @Midavalo repaired the arcgis setup, then did the same with the 64 bit background processing and I still have the same errors

Comment: @Midavalo I have ArcGIS for Server installed as well

Comment: i ended up uninstalling arcgis for desktop and the 64 bit processing. reinstalled the argis for desktop first then the 64 bit and it worked

Comment: Cross-posted as http://stackoverflow.com/q/42721143/820534 Please do not cross-post

Comment: @PolyGeo why no cross-post?

Comment: http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/4068/115

Comment: @ziggy Please post your solution as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trying all the suggestions posted to no avail I simply ended up uninstalling arcgis for desktop and the 64 bit processing. reinstalled the argis for desktop first then the 64 bit and it worked